# Inner (Dot) Product Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

Say for all continuously differentiable vector fields $w \in C^\infty_c (\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d) $ with compact support. (Note $ w : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$), I have the

$$     \big\langle v (y) ,w(y) \big\rangle  = L(w(y)), ~ \text{where}~ L:C^\infty_c (\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d)\to \mathbb{R} $$

Can I use this to get a bound of the form

$$ \|v(y)\| \leq f(y,w(y),L(w(y)) $$

for some other functional $f$ ?

Comment: What's to stop me adding to $v$ an arbitrarily large multiple of a vector orthogonal to $w$, thereby increasing $\Vert v\Vert$ without bound?

Comment: nothing you are right, thanks :)